# How to say "deserve" in Japanese

Tags: word-requests

As in the title, how can I say "I don't deserve your present" in Japanese? Google translate tells me it's あなたのプレゼントに値しません。First off, the verb doesn't seem to be correct. Secondly, can I use を instead of に here to get あなたのプレゼント**を**値しません？

If memory serves me right, I have heard "僕にはプレゼントをもらう権利がない", which translates to "I don't have the rights to receive the present", but that sounds a bit different than I don't deserve your present.

Comment: Good question, IMO there’s no direct equivalent in Japanese and you often need to just stay something different, or use a word choice that sounds more stilted than the English.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks for the info. I suppose using あなたのプレゼントに値しません would still get the meaning across?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> あなたのプレゼントに値しません。... can I use を instead of に here to get あなたのプレゼントを値しません？

～**に**[値]{あたい}しない means "doesn't deserve~~", and あなたのプレゼントに値しません is the *literal* translation of "don't deserve your present". プレゼント**を**値しない is grammatically incorrect.

Saying あなたのプレゼントに値しません in your situation would be pretty unnatural, and also sound like you're refusing the present.

> I don't deserve your present.

To mean that, I think you could say...

> 私には**もったいない**です。/
>   私には**もったいないくらい**です。

(closer to "It's (almost) too good for me.")

Comment: Wouldn't the literal translation (あなたのプレゼントに値しません) be better compared to 私にはもったいないです? Or is it just weird for japanese to put it in literal translation?

Comment: あなたのプレゼントに値しません would be pretty unnatural and weird, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd assume it'd still get the message accross? albeit in a very weird way

Comment: If you said あなたのプレゼントに値しません or 僕にはプレゼントをもらう権利がない, you'd be understood as refusing/declining to accept the present.

Comment: Sounds like it changes the meaning completely. Safe to say あなたのプレゼントに値しません would actually mean a different thing?

Comment: @Newbie I think you could literally understand “~に値しない” as “I don’t have the value for ~”, which can in some cases be used to translate “deserve” but often is awkward. In this case it sounds way too heavy (as receiving a present doesn’t really have to do with someone’s value seriously).